# IE 7/8 CSS div size problem with a img background

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm designing a clean style to use in some web apps. And I've come across a IE bug (always the same).

Well its pretty simple. I have a gradient background, and on top of it a rectangle with no border and its filled with nothing and with a shadow around it, giving the illusion that its on top of the background, as you can see in the [snapshot](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/1123/firefoxg.png).

Its displayed well in all browsers except IE. IE displays like [this](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/420/68727100.png).

---

IE increases about 4 px to the top div with the class "content-top-shadow". And it shouldn't. I have used margin and padding 0 to fix it and no luck.

PS: The png's have transparency.

Any idea how can i fix this bug, or whats wrong in the CSS?

Thanks.

**Here is the code:**

**HTML**

```
    <div class="content-holder">
        <div class="content-center">
            <div class="content-top-shadow"></div>
            <div class="content-center-holder"></div>
            <div class="content-bottom-shadow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 570px; /*once complete change to auto*/
    background-image: url(images/content-holder-bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center; /*IE Bug Fix to Center the other divs inside this one*/
}
.content-center {
    width: 918px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.content-top-shadow {
    width: 918px;
    height: 9px;
    background-image: url(images/content-top-shadow-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.content-center-holder {
    width: 918px;
    height: 200px; /*once complete change to auto*/
    background-image: url(images/content-center-holder-bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.content-bottom-shadow {
    width: 918px;
    height: 9px;
    background-image: url(images/content-bottom-shadow-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE thinks your div should be bigger than 9px, because of text size, even if there is no text in it (!), so you need to set

```
font-size:1px;
```

or something like that, on the top and bottom divs.

Comment: Your right it worked. Strange that the bottom div doesn't have that problem. Once it should have.

Comment: The bottom div DOES have that problem, you just don't see it because the background img in it is top aligned, and the gap is below it. ;)

Comment: You're right. I've selected the div and its bigger than 9px. I didn't noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that helps me overcome cross-browser incompatibilites when it comes to empty spaces especially within DIVs and TDs. Place this as the sole content of the empty space, while making sure your spacer.gif image is a 1px x 1px transparent dot. Cheers!

`<div style="width:1px;height:1px;visibility:hidden;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);color:#FFFFFF;font-size:1px;"><img src="/images/spacer.gif"></div>`

Comment: Fortunately i haven't had that problem yet, but will come in handy. thanks.